# Why don't the app icon in title bar display when I create an app with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Before I created Android App with eclipse, it can display the app icon in the left side of the title bar , please see the image aa.png.

Now I create Android App with Android Studio, I have add the code `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` to manifest.xml file, but the app icon don't display, please see the image bb.png, why?

BTW, The icon can display if I replace `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'` with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'`, why?  are there some bugs with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 ?

**aa.png**

[image]

**bb.png**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cuiwei.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cuiwei.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}

<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Any more ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If it doesn't work, you should call `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(Drawable/int)` or `getSupportActionBar().setLogo(Drawable/int)`in your `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks! but getSupportActionBar().setIcon(@mipmap/ic_launcher); display error

Comment: Oh, come on. `setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)`.

Comment: BTW, icon don't display after I add  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" to <activity> </activity>

Comment: so you need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the code setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) , but icon don't display yet

Comment: I place the app to dropbox, you can download and test it at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/MyApplication.zip

Comment: Maybe you should try a logo. check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: Thanks! The icon can display if I replace compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' with compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0', are there some bugs with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 ?

Comment: Could you give me a smple code for how to logo to display app icon?

Comment: try `getSupportActionBar().setLogo(Drawable/int)`

Comment: No, It don't display app icon after I add getSupportActionBar().setLogo(Drawable/int)

Answer (score 2):

Using Android 5.0 styles (i.e., AppCompat), the app icon does not display in the action bar.

You should be able to see the app icon if you use the Android Holo theme.  To do so, change android:theme to "android:Theme.Holo" or "android:Theme.Holo.Light".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank! but "android:Theme.Holo.Light" required min API  is 11, now my min API is 9.  I have imported "import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity".